# Salesforce Junction Objects

Tags: salesforce

To all salesforce experts i need some assistance. I have my contacts and a custom object named programs. I created a junction object using to master detail relationships with contacts and programs. I want to avoid relating the same contact to the same program. I tried triggers but I couldn't create the testing part to use it outside sandbox.

I went back to the basics and created a Unique text field. I tried to use default value but EVERYTHING i write in that crap is wrong -_-. I tried `Contact__r.Email & "-" & Program__r.Name` but to no avail.

I tried workflow rules with a field update but my field update NEVER runs.(Yes I did activate the workflow rule) and I didn't know what to write in my rule's code.

Answer (score 3):

The workflow firing condition could be simply a formula that says `true`. Alternatively use "every time record is inserted". It also depends whether your master-details are set once and that's it or they will be "reparentable" (option introduced in Summer '12 I think). Maybe post a screenshot / text description of your firing condition? Also - is your unique field set to "case sensitive"?

As for the formula to populate the unique field - something like `Contact__c + ' ' + Program__c` (or whatever the API names of your fields are) should be OK. Don't use `Contact__r.Email` etc as these don't have to be unique...

You'll have to somehow fill in the uniqueness criteria for all existing records (maybe that's why you claimed it doesn't work?). If you can use Apex for data fixes - something like this should get you started.

```
List<Junction__c> junctions = [SELECT Contact__c, Program__c 
FROM Junction__c 
WHERE Unique_Text_Field__c = null 
LIMIT 10000];

for(Junction__c j : junctions){
   String key = String.valueOf(j.Contact__c).left(15) + ' ' + String.valueOf(j.Program__c).left(15);
   j.Unique_Text_Field__c = key;
}

update junctions;
```

Keep rerunning it until it starts to show 0 rows processed. The Ids are cut down to 15 chars because in Apex you'd usually see full 18-char Id but workflows use 15-char versions.